# Catalog > Manage Categories entrypoint not visible (Also tabs are missing)

Tags: magento-1.9, category, product-list, tabs

I am making a custom module which has a functionality to sell products on magento website. I have used `customer groups` to define `sellers` and made a custom module, but suddenly `categories entry point went missing`. When i click on Catalog > Manage Catgories it shows products listing there, and when i click on `Add Subcategory` it does nothing but just refreshes itself, and product listing remains the same.

Also it is not showing the default tabs when we click on `Add Subcategory`

- General Information
- Display Settings
- Custom Design

But it only shows `Category products` all the above 3 are missing.

I didn't change anything in my custom module related to categories. Please guide me what am i doing wrong here. Below is my screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First go to admin->system/manage store and check whether the Root category is set to default category(root category:default category).

Then check whether the category you created are sub-categories of the default category.

I think This link will help you-> [link](http://www.aschroder.com/2009/03/top-3-solutions-when-your-magento-categories-are-not-displaying/)  Refer the screenshots in it.

Comment: Thanx for the reply, i have seen the link  you referred but it didn't helped, i have tried all 3 solutions that `Schroder` has given but no luck.

Comment: which magento version are you using? CE or EE?

Comment: i am using CE 1.9.2.2

Comment: Did you import sample data successfully?

Comment: No i am not using Sample Data.
i added 6 products of my own.

Comment: No.During installation process you need to import magento sample data into your database created. Didn't you import it?

Comment: No. I didn't imported sample data, products and categories are blank after successful install.

Comment: So the mistake is that. You need to import the magento sample data once you create the database.

Comment: O really, let me try that with the fresh install, and will get back to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34955/discussion-between-ramya-and-soeb-safi).

Comment: Did you import sample data?